# Why are multiple connections being created in my database?

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js

I am developing a website in NextJs and using MongoDB as a database. This code is what connects to the database and keeps it in cache.

```
    import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";

    let cache = {};

    export default async function connect() {
      if (cache?.client?.isConnected()) {
        return cache;
      }
     
      const opts = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true,
      };

      return MongoClient.connect(process.env.DATABASE_URL, opts).then((client) => {
        cache = {
          db: client.db("bd"),
          client,
        };
        return {
          client,
          db: client.db("bd"),
        };
      });
    }
```

I imagine that this code should cause only 1 connection to be created but it is creating many more connections. As in the photo below, 18 connections were created and dropped to 6 after I stopped use the site. Why are several connections being created? How do you make it just one?

[image]

This is an example of code that I am using on one of the routes to list users.

```
          ...
          const { db, client } = await connect();
          const { userThatMakeRequest } = req;
          const { group } = req.query;

          const users = await db
            .collection("user")
            .find(
              {
                roles: "team-user",
                "team.id": userThatMakeRequest?.team?.id,
                "group.id": group,
                hasAccess: true,
              },
              { projection: { password: 0 } }
            )
            .toArray();

          res.status(200).json({
            response: users || [],
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

The driver creates 1 or 2 connections to each known server for monitoring purposes. Application connections (the ones used for satisfying queries and writes) are separate.

If you create a client object and perform one query against a 3 node replica set running MongoDB 4.4, you'll end up with 7 total connections.

Comment: if 70 users log in then do i use as many connections as possible? (500)